# In Internet Explorer (IE) , URL Querystring issue with special character

Tags: internet-explorer, query-string

There is issue with special character in INTERNET EXPLORER browser.

It's working fine in Google Chrome and Firefox but having issue with **Internet Explorer**.

I've word **višina** from **Slovensko** language which have special character "š".

URL is :http://localhost:53509/posode-za-vino?ra_Skupna višina Z mm_146=1621.3-5500

In Firefox it: ra_Skupna višina Z mm_146
This is perfect.

[Check snap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BIGA.png)

But while I'm checking with Internet Explorer, 
Querystring looks like: ra_Skupna vi�ina Z mm_146

[check snap here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHB68.png)

Here special character **š** is replaced with **�**.

This is working fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Let me know if anyone have idea about this issue with Internet Exploer

Comment: I fixed with encoded parameter.
First encode value than pass in URL as parameter. 

so it working  as Query string read data as encoded formate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed with encoded parameter.
 First encode value than pass in URL as parameter.
 so it working as Query string read data as encoded format.